# How to rearrange items from a contextmenustrip?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, contextmenustrip

How do I rearrange items of a `ContextMenuStrip`? For example if I create a windows forms app with a button and add a `ContextMenuStrip` to the form and assign it on the button click event and add items in the sequence

```
run process1
run process2
run process3
```

and then after some day I decide to add another item to the `ContextMenuStrip` say "run process4" and I want the sequence to be something like

```
run process1
run process4
run process2
run process3
```

How can I do that (apart from renaming every single item and interchanging the codes on each of the click event)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to `Add` items you can also `Insert` item at specified index:

```
this.contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add("Item1");
this.contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add("Item2");
this.contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add("Item3");
this.contextMenuStrip1.Items.Insert(1, new ToolStripMenuItem("Item4"));
```

Comment: I do not see the `Item4` when I click on the ContextMenuStrip on the form but when I run the program `Item4` does appear on button click...why is this happening? Also how do I add a click event on `Item4` if I can't see it in my form?

Comment: The code I shared in the answer is for adding items at run-time. If your question is regarding to the design-time, you can simply reorder item by drag-and-drop or using `Items` collection of the `ContextMenuStrip`.

Comment: To add `Click` event handler, for run-time, `ToolStripMenuItem` has a constructor with 3 argument, second parameter is image, and the third one is click event handler. Also for design-time, simply add the event handler using `Events` tab of the property grid.